# WPF add html string to HTML file and save it

Tags: c#, html, wpf

i have WPF application which have an HTML string as below.
how can i creeate a new HTML file base on this string and save this file in my application folder in code behind?

```
string str = "<h2><u>TEST</u></h2><div style='margin:0 auto;'>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("document.html", FileMode.Create)) 
{ 
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8)) 
    { 
        sw.WriteLine("<h2><u>TEST</u></h2><div style='margin:0 auto;'>"); 
    } 
}
```